# What GPO settings will allow non-admin users to add wireless printer

Tags: group-policy, installation, printing

I've configured GPO settings to allow non-admins users to add printers.  The two settings are:

- Computer Configuration/Policies/Administrative
  Templates/System/Driver Installation/Allow non-administrators to
  install drivers for these device setup classes  (I've added the class
  GUID for printers `{4D36E979-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`)
- User Configuration/Polices/Administrative Templates/Control
  Panel/Printers/Point and Print Restrictions (Disabled)

I've verified that these settings work when adding a printer using Add Printer from Devices and Printers menu.  However, users are not able to add a wireless printer using Add Device.  I've tried adding the class GUID for printers to the Device Installation Restrictions/Allow installation of devices using drivers that match these device setup classes, but the user is still prompted for admin password.

The printer she is trying to install is a *HP Officejet 4650*.  It is wireless and she can print from other devices at her home.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with printer driver installation? Perhaps the problem with the user's wireless network configuration in which the printer working? May be firewall rules?

Comment: If you connect to it shared, does you see a driver prompt ?